# How to unselect features in ONLY the current layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, vector, features, select

How does one unselect features only from a certain layer?

I know there's the Deselect features from ALL layers button. But that's extreme. Is there a simple way to unselect features ONLY from (say) the current layer?

I can only think to ctrl+click everything, but this hardly seems effective.

Comment: Open the attribute table and hit the unselect button. see http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2010/10/working-with-attribute-table-basic.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you click in empty space (not touching any features of the current layer) with the select tool the current layer will drop it's selection.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>QGIS 3.0.2 answer</sub>.

Besides what [Jakob said](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136361/how-do-i-unselect-features-in-only-the-current-layer-in-qgis/136367#136367), with the layer selected open the TOC and hit the `Deselect all` button (or its shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + A`). See screenshot below:

[image]

Still in the TOC, if one wants to deselect only a few rows of a previous selection, hold Ctrl and click on rows to be deselected.

---

The following shows how to deselect with pyQGIS: [Where is the QGIS API action for "deselect"?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155709/where-is-the-qgis-api-action-for-deselect)