# Where is the QGIS API action for "deselect"?

Tags: pyqgis

Where is the QGIS action for the “deselect” toolbutton in the 'Attributes" toolbar? I do not see this action in the QgisInterface class or do not recognize it by name.  Is it missing from iface?

I'd like to use this action in a plugin directly instead of the button on the toolbar.

Comment: I believe the _Deselect_ function is from the [QgsVectorLayer](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a61c56ba7370a9c3f354b5f75fbffaad7) class.

Comment: Yes, That is probably what I mean.  The toolbar turns on/off with 'Attributes' in the View/Toolbars menu item and the tooltip is "Deselect Features from all Layers'. In any case, I do not see it in iface.

Comment: Where did the comment I responded to go?  Yes, 'UnSelect' is probably what I mean.

Comment: Yes sorry, I realised that you meant another button on the main interface (there is an _Unselect all_ button from the Attribute Table interface) so I removed it from the comment.

Comment: Yes, the one on the Attribute Table interface has the same icon. I am looking for the on the main interface in the 'Attributes' toolbar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the attributes toolbar and iterate through its actions (buttons) until you get the "deselect" one. Then you can trigger it.

Try this in your QGIS Python console:

```
for a in iface.attributesToolBar().actions(): 
  if a.objectName() == 'mActionDeselectAll':
    a.trigger()
    break
```

Comment: Thanks, This will work. I'll just have to search for the action in my setup instead of just getting it from iface.

Answer (score 8):

In QGIS 3.4 using Python Console, also is

```
iface.activeLayer() 
vlayer.removeSelection()
```

Comment: Really Easy! This could/(should?) be something like:
vlayer = iface.activeLayer()
vlayer.removeSelection()

Answer (score 7):

I was stuck on the same issue. I found in http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#selecting-features

`layer.setSelectedFeatures([])`

it will just select an empty list and so clear selection.

Answer (score 4):

I guess, the removeSelection thing also works!

```
legend=iface.legendInterface()
layers=legend.layers()
for layer in layers():
    layer.removeSelection()
```

Answer (score 1):

Brute force ;-) A new selection overrides the old one. Then simply deselect by selecting nothing.

```
for layer_id in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers():
layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayer(layer_id)
    layer.setSelectedFeatures([feat.id() \
        for feat in layer.selectedFeaturesIterator() if feat.id() < 0])
```

Maybe there is a more distinguished method, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

For QGIS 3 it will be

```
layer.deselect(feature_id_here)
```

https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.10/core/QgsVectorLayer.html?highlight=deselect#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.deselect